# AWS Lambda Python - which API Gateway method is used to invoke the function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am working on AWS Lambda function based on Python. I have a trigger - API Gateway with 2 methods - Get and POST.
I feel so stupid, but i can't figure out how to capture which method was used to call the function. I know the event and context arguments don't contain this, but where can i get this info?

Answer (score 2):

> I know the event and context arguments don't contain this

The event object absolutely does contain this information. Unless you have configured custom event mapping in API Gateway, the event object will be in the format described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event).

You can see the HTTP Method is in the `httpMethod` property of the event.

Comment: That was it.. I am using custom mapping. I just had to add httpMethod in the mapping template and i can now get it properly. Thanks for the hint :)